# Any ideas of how make internal a base class implementation having a child class of that class public in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, visibility, public, internal

Any ideas of how make internal a base class having a child class of that class public in c#?

In code:

```
internal class Base { }

public class Child : Base {}
```

I have a layered architecture and need to expose to other layers (others assemblies) the Child class but not the Base class. I'm using inherit as a way to avoid class composition and all the voile part associated with it.

Any ideas of how to manage this kind of problem?

Comment: Do `public abstract Base`. This way, although you're exposing `Base`, you can't instantiate it.

Comment: Why avoid composition? You can autogenerate passthrough implementation with ReSharper or T4, hide it in a partial class and even mark it as DependsOn so two always go together like a codebehind file.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What you said not solve my problem: avoid up layers cluttering and hide down layers implementations, minimizing the public surface.

Comment: @IlyaKozhevnikov I will consider what you said as an option, but I'm really not a fan of such kind of compositions: 1- Too much extra code just dedicate to layer surface minimization; 2- I don't have clear that the refactoring of the Base (in your case the composite class) will be an smooth task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the class internal, you can make all members internal instead. If you do not want `Base` to be inherited by other assemblies, declare `Base`'s constructor as internal.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer as the right one even I consider all answers and comments useful because in my opinion this is the answer that give a more or less decent solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. You can hide the class by encapsulation, wrapping it and hiding it as implementation.

Base types will always be known.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but wrapping is precisely what I'm trying to avoid with my question ;) See my reply comments on the question itself.

Comment: @gsc-frank I think that the quality of the answers would go up significantly if you would explain what you are trying to accomplish. Should the base class be unknown? Do you want to make it Impossible to inherit from the base class? Do you want to be able to swap the bad class without breaking the contract? ...

Comment: As I said in other comments: is just a matter of minimization of modules surface, a very important thing in large projects. I don't want class `Base` be accessible at all outside the module that define it Explains the architecture things that lead me to that need is out of scope of this pure technical question.

Answer (score 0):

This is known C# limitation, however, this is not CLR limitation.

Not the best solution, but it's possible to define new public class which inherits from internal class, using intermediate language.

Also, there might be some languages which already allow you to do this, so there is a chance you don't really need to write IL.

Though, at this point, I don't understand the necessity of `Base`. Since it's internal, it can't be consumed by others, and `polymorpishm` is essentially broken. Code reuse with subclassing, but without polymorpishm does not sound good.

Thugh, as I said, imh it is possibe to create a "public" class from "internal class" using IL, after that, yu will be able to consume that "public" class in C# side, eg

```
public class MyDervClass : MyILPublicClass{}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic, but is it CLS-compliant?

Comment: In my case the necessity of `Base` class is avoid code duplication.